# AngularJS multilevel routing reload issue

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, url-rewriting, angularjs-routing

I am working on AngularJs with HTML5 mode enabled for SEO friendly URLs, its working fine with the in app navigation but on reload.

Have written below `.htaccess` but still facing the same issues for nested navigation

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /akv/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpeg|gif|)
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Its working fine for fist level navigation like `base/Blog` or `base/Portfolio` but `base/Blog/MyBlogTitle/type/post/id/1`

Is there is any way to fix it.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What error are you getting? Why do you have `RewriteBase /akv/` and how many .htaccess files you have under DocumentRoot?

Comment: I have only one .httaccess file in Root, akv is sub-folder created for dev purpose and having all the source code.
There is no such errors but the resources like css and js are trying to load from the url like `base/akv/Blogs/SampleTitle/type/category/id/css/style.css`

Comment: Still not clear. What is the exact error you're facing here. I don't get what you mean by **Its working fine for fist level navigation like base/Blog or base/Portfolio but base/Blog/MyBlogTitle/type/post/id/1** There is no `/akv/` in `base/Blog/MyBlogTitle/type/post/id/1` URL.

Comment: /akv/ is a part of base

Comment: Ok! Here is the situation

When I open the URL 
`ashokvishwakarma.in/akv/Blogs`,
`ashokvishwakarma.in/akv/Portfolio`
`ashokvishwakarma.in/akv`

Its load resources from 

`ashokvishwakarma.in/akvlko/css/cssfile.css`,
`ashokvishwakarma.in/akvlko/js/jsfile.js` 
`ashokvishwakarma.in/akvlko/img/image.png` 

but when I open the page 

`ashokvishwakarma.in/akv/Blogs/BlogTitle/type/post/id/10`

it start loading resources from 

`ashokvishwakarma.in/akv/Blogs/BlogTitle/type/post/id/css/cssfile.css` 

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you're using relative URLs in your css/image/js paths. Relative URLs are resolved as browser adds them to the current path thus giving you 404 when using pretty URLs.

To fix this problem you can add this in your page's HTML `<head>` section:

```
<base href="/kv/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.